# Antlr4 how to build a grammar allowed keywords as identifier

Tags: parsing, antlr, antlr4, peg

This is a demo code

```
label:
var id
let id = 10
goto label
```

If allowed keyword as identifier will be

```
let:
var var
let var = 10
goto let
```

This is totally legal code. But it seems very hard to do this in antlr.

AFAIK, If antlr match a token let, will never fallback to id token. so for antlr it will see

```
LET_TOKEN :
VAR_TOKEN <missing ID_TOKEN>VAR_TOKEN
LET_TOKEN <missing ID_TOKEN>VAR_TOKEN = 10
```

although antlr allowed [predicate](https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/blob/master/doc/predicates.md), I have to control ever token match and problematic. grammar become this

```
grammar Demo;
options {
  language = Go;
}
@parser::members{
    var _need = map[string]bool{}
    func skip(name string,v bool){
        _need[name] = !v
        fmt.Println("SKIP",name,v)
    }
    func need(name string)bool{
        fmt.Println("NEED",name,_need[name])
        return _need[name]
    }
}

proj@init{skip("inst",false)}: (line? NL)* EOF;
line
    : VAR ID
    | LET ID EQ? Integer
    ;

NL: '\n';
VAR: {need("inst")}? 'var' {skip("inst",true)};
LET: {need("inst")}? 'let' {skip("inst",true)};
EQ: '=';

ID: ([a-zA-Z] [a-zA-Z0-9]*);
Integer: [0-9]+;

WS: [ \t] -> skip;
```

Looks so terrible.

But this is easy in peg, test this in [pegjs](https://pegjs.org/online)

```
Expression = (Line? _ '\n')* ;

Line
  = 'var' _ ID
  / 'let' _ ID _ "=" _ Integer

Integer "integer"
  = [0-9]+ { return parseInt(text(), 10); }

ID = [a-zA-Z] [a-zA-Z0-9]*

_ "whitespace"
  = [ \t]*
```

I actually done this in [peggo](https://github.com/wenerme/bbvm/blob/master/libbbvm/parser/bbasm.peg) and [javacc](https://github.com/wenerme/bbvm/blob/master/jbbvm/bbvm-core/src/main/jjtree/me/wener/bbvm/asm/BBAsmParser.jjt).

My question is how to handle these grammars in antlr4.6, I was so excited about the antlr4.6 go target, but seems I choose the wrong tool for my grammar ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The simplest way is to define a parser rule for identifiers:

```
id: ID | VAR | LET;

VAR: 'var';
LET: 'let';
ID: [a-zA-Z] [a-zA-Z0-9]*;
```

And then use `id` instead of `ID` in your parser rules.

A different way is to use `ID` for identifiers *and* keywords, and use predicates for disambiguation. But it's less readable, so I'd use the first way instead.

Comment: Unfortunately in this situation, when an error message is generated by antlr4, it tells the user that either ID, var or let is expected, which is confusing. Do you know if there a way to get antlr4 to tell the user that only ID is expected?

Comment: @user1241663 good point. I never really tried to customize error messages, but I suppose you could supply your own `IParserErrorListener` to tweak the generated errors. I don't know if there's a better way.

Comment: Extending `DefaultErrorStrategy` lets me customize the error message.