# google query like antlr4 learning example. How can I get the value string and why stops consuming early with the defined value?

Tags: antlr4

Just, as a learning process, I want to simulate a shorter version of the Google advanced search queries [1]. In this case using only "site" and "filetype" keywords. Therefore I need to:

1. Interpret everything except keywords:values as text query (query_string in the grammar)
2. Interpret the defined keywords:values (binary_op in the grammar)

**Input**: "text to search site:foo"

**Current results**

The current grammar (posted below) and with the defined input fails with:

```
line 1:0 extraneous input 'text' expecting {'(', SITE, FILETYPE, STRING}
(start (logic_expr text (expr (query_string  ))))
```

**Expected results**

With the defined grammar I would expect this other result:

```
(start (logic_expr (expr (query_string t e x t   t o   s e a r c h  )) (expr (binary_op (varname site) : (value foo)))))
```

**Questions**

1. Why the grammar fails with the first element of the text ?
2. If I change the "value" rule to STRING and comment the VALUE lexer rule it almost works but it does not follow the requeriments. Of course, it only consumes the value as non-greedy.

   2.1 Now, in the grammar I can comment or not the VALUE rule. Why the behavior changes that much even if I am not using the VALUE rule ?, I tried swapping the STRING and VALUE rules but it does not affect the results.

**GRAMMAR**

```
grammar Google;

// Fragments (not tokens)
fragment A: ('a' | 'A'); // match either an 'a' or 'A'
fragment B: ('b' | 'B');
fragment C: ('c' | 'C');
fragment D: ('d' | 'D');
fragment E: ('e' | 'E');
fragment F: ('f' | 'F');
fragment G: ('g' | 'G');
fragment H: ('h' | 'H');
fragment I: ('i' | 'I');
fragment J: ('j' | 'J');
fragment K: ('k' | 'K');
fragment L: ('l' | 'L');
fragment M: ('m' | 'M');
fragment N: ('n' | 'N');
fragment O: ('o' | 'O');
fragment P: ('p' | 'P');
fragment Q: ('q' | 'Q');
fragment R: ('r' | 'R');
fragment S: ('s' | 'S');
fragment T: ('t' | 'T');
fragment U: ('u' | 'U');
fragment V: ('v' | 'V');
fragment W: ('w' | 'W');
fragment X: ('x' | 'X');
fragment Y: ('y' | 'Y');
fragment Z: ('z' | 'Z');

// Lexer rules (tokens)
WHITE_SPACE: [\t\r\n] -> skip;  // Every space like except the space properly

AND : A N D;
OR  : O R;

SITE: S I T E;
FILETYPE: F I L E T Y P E;
// ... other keywords ...

VALUE: (~[ ])+;  // Everything except space. Fails if enabled. Why ?
STRING: .+?;  // Non-greedy comsumption



// Grammar

start: logic_expr ;

logic_expr
    : '(' logic_expr+ ')'           # parenthesis_logic_expr_operator
    | logic_expr (AND logic_expr)+  # and_logic_expr_operator
    | logic_expr (OR logic_expr)+   # or_logic_expr_operator
    | expr+                         # terminal_logic_expr_operator
    ;


expr
    : (query_string | binary_op) ;

query_string: STRING+;

varname
    : SITE
    | FILETYPE
    // others ..
    ;

value: VALUE;

binary_op
    : varname ':' value;
```

[1] - https://support.google.com/websearch/answer/2466433?hl=en

Answer (score 0):

ANTLR's lexer rules are greedy by default. So if you do `VALUE: (~[ ])+;`, it will match `site:foo` (and will not match the parser rule `binary_op : varname ':' value;`!). Also, when doing `STRING : .+?;` is will only ever match 1 character. The `.+?` should only be used if it is followed by a terminating character.

> `WHITE_SPACE: [\t\r\n] -> skip;  // Every space like except the space properly`

Why? In your use case, you do need to skip spaces AFAIK.

I've (slightly) edited your grammar so that it works with your input:

```
grammar Google;

// Grammar
start: logic_expr EOF;

logic_expr
    : '(' logic_expr+ ')'           # parenthesis_logic_expr_operator
    | logic_expr (AND logic_expr)+  # and_logic_expr_operator
    | logic_expr (OR logic_expr)+   # or_logic_expr_operator
    | expr+                         # terminal_logic_expr_operator
    ;


expr
    : (query_string | binary_op) ;

query_string: STRING+;

varname
    : SITE
    | FILETYPE
    // others ..
    ;

value: STRING;

binary_op
    : varname ':' value;

// Lexer rules (tokens)
WHITE_SPACE: [ \t\r\n] -> skip;

AND : A N D;
OR  : O R;

SITE: S I T E;
FILETYPE: F I L E T Y P E;
// ... other keywords ...

STRING: ~[ :]+;

// Fragments (not tokens)
fragment A: [aA];
fragment B: [bB];
fragment C: [cC];
fragment D: [dD];
fragment E: [eE];
fragment F: [fF];
fragment G: [gG];
fragment H: [hH];
fragment I: [iI];
fragment J: [jJ];
fragment K: [kK];
fragment L: [lL];
fragment M: [mM];
fragment N: [nN];
fragment O: [oO];
fragment P: [pP];
fragment Q: [qQ];
fragment R: [rR];
fragment S: [sS];
fragment T: [tT];
fragment U: [uU];
fragment V: [vV];
fragment W: [wW];
fragment X: [xX];
fragment Y: [yY];
fragment Z: [zZ];
```

Main changes are:

- removed `VALUE`
- changed `STRING : .+?;` into `STRING: ~[ :]+;`
- changed `WHITE_SPACE: [\t\r\n] -> skip;` to `WHITE_SPACE: [ \t\r\n] -> skip;`

And if you want to support syntax like `site:site` (see [Antlr4 how to build a grammar allowed keywords as identifier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41421644/antlr4-how-to-build-a-grammar-allowed-keywords-as-identifier)), you need to change:

```
value: STRING;
```

into:

```
value: STRING | varname;
```

Comment: "So if you do VALUE: (~[ ])+;, it will match site:foo ....", means that lexer rules are applied in the order of appearance in the file ?, I was guessing they were used, if and only if ,some parsing rule is calling the lexer rule. Am I wrong ?

Comment: @XavierPegenaute no, the lexer operates independently from the parser, it doesn't matter if a parser rule is trying to match a certain token, the lexer just tries to create the longest possible token. The order of lexer rules is only considered when 2 (or more) rules match the same amount of characters. Only then the first rule "wins". Besides that, the longest match wins.