# ANTLR4 grammar handling reserved keywords that appear inside "free-text" fields

Tags: antlr4

I'm attempting to write an ANTLR4 grammar for [lookml](https://cloud.google.com/looker/docs/reference/lookml-quick-reference). The schema for this language is relatively straight forward but it has 2 wrinkles -- 1 is that it supports a templating language that can be used in most "properties" and 2 there are a few fields that allow for arbitrary sql expressions.

My issue has to do with how the lexer gets tokens in different contexts.

LookML has a property for [case/when expressions](https://cloud.google.com/looker/docs/reference/param-field-case) for example:

```
dimension: query_type {
    type: string
    case: {
      when: {
        label: "SELECT Query"
        sql: ${name} ILIKE 'SELECT%'
          ;;
      }
      else: 'Other'
  }
}
```

so I have tokens in my lexer:

```
CASE: 'case';
WHEN: 'when';
ELSE: 'else';
```

But you can also have CASE/WHEN statements in the arbitrary SQL fields

```
dimension: full_name {
  type: string
  sql: case when true then 'its true' else 'its false' end ;;
}
```

My parser rule for the sql expression can't just "catch all" everything between the `sql:` and the `;;` because there could be template variables that I want parsed. When the lexer runs it considers the `CASE` `WHEN` as the reserved keywords intended to match up with the `case` `when` properties. My `sql` property rule then needs to account for `CASE | WHEN | ELSE` and really any reserved keyword in lookml that could also find its way in arbitrary SQL code.

**I've considered a few options:**

1. As I'm testing and developing I can add every possible token into my `sql` property parser rule and let the tokenizer think that those are tokens.
2. Make the lexer treat everything between `sql:` and `;;` as one big token and handle parsing the possible template values in the application code
3. Making the tokens *include* the colon so CASE becomes `'case:'`

Are any of these common approaches to this problem? This is my first grammar from scratch so I could be missing the point entirely here. I also tried looking into modes but I can't tell if that is actually the right application here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When parsing a language inside a language (SQL inside LookML), you could use [lexical modes](https://github.com/tunnelvisionlabs/antlr4/blob/master/doc/lexer-rules.md#lexical-modes). When using lexical modes, you'll need to separate the lexer- and parser-grammars.

A quick demo:

##### LookMLLexer.g4

```
lexer grammar LookMLLexer;

DIMENSION : 'dimension';
SQL : 'sql' SPACE* ':' -> pushMode(SqlMode);
CASE : 'case';
WHEN : 'when';
ELSE : 'else';

COL : ':';
OBRACE :  '{';
CBRACE : '}';

STRING : '"' .*? '"';

ID : [a-zA-Z_] [a-zA-Z_0-9]*;
COMMENT : '#' ~[\r\n]* -> skip;
SPACES : SPACE+ -> skip;

OTHER : .;

fragment SPACE : [ \t\r\n];

mode SqlMode;

SCOL2 : ';;' -> popMode;
SELECT options { caseInsensitive = true; } : 'select';
FROM options { caseInsensitive = true; } : 'from';
SQL_ID : ID -> type(ID);
SQL_SPACES : SPACE+ -> skip;
```

##### LookMLParser.g4

```
parser grammar LookMLParser;

options {
  tokenVocab=LookMLLexer;
}

parse
 : dimension EOF
 ;

dimension
 : DIMENSION ':' ID '{' case_when key_value* '}'
 ;

case_when
 : CASE ':' '{' when+ else '}'
 ;

when
 : WHEN ':' '{' sql key_value* '}'
 ;

else
 : ELSE ':' value
 ;

key_value
 : ID ':' value
 ;

value
 : STRING
 | ID
 ;

sql
 : SQL sql_stat SCOL2
 ;

sql_stat
 : SELECT ID FROM ID
 ;
```

will parse the input:

```
dimension: field_name {
  case: {
    when: {
      sql: SELECT a FROM b ;;
      label: "value"
    }
    # Possibly more when statements
    else: "value"
  }
  alpha_sort:  yes
}
```

as follows:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the help @bart -- this looks promising. I'm going to try out lexical modes. I've reviewed the docs for modes and I have read that section of the Definitive ANTLR 4 Reference that covers this. The code snippet really helps clarify it for my use case. I already have the separate lexer/parser files so I at least have that part out of the way.

One unrelated question on your code snippet while I have you is -- what is benefit/convention around using `'{'` in your parser rules vs using `OBRACE` from the lexer?

Comment: Another related question @BartKiers -- are modes the way you handle a case where someone names a dimension a reserved keyword? For example if I have a dimension named "label" -- `dimension: label { ...` -- the lexer will think that "label" in this context is the dimension property called "label". Would I need to enter a mode at `dimension` and then pop out at `{`? I could see that proliferating quite a bit -- I would effectively have to enter a mode for every lookml property but maybe that is the only way to make sure that "label" is tokenized as `ID`

Comment: @jsnb "what is benefit/convention around using '{' in your parser rules vs using OBRACE from the lexer?" only brevity. You can also use `OBRACE` in the parser. And regarding keywords as identifiers, something like this is a common approach: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41421644/antlr4-how-to-build-a-grammar-allowed-keywords-as-identifier

Comment: This is working out really well. It feels natural to be solving this in the lexer and it is making my parsing rule much more readable. For my purposes I really only need the looker template variables and I can discard the actual SQL part of the `sql:` properties so I can make a "catch all - everything until ${" token and its limited to my sql mode.